# CoreBluetooth or the EAAccessoryManager and hands free

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, mfi, eaaccessory

Is it possible to know if an iPhone is paired with the hands free system in a car using the CoreBluetooth or the EAAccessoryManager? If not, is there another way to do it?

Comment: BLE isn't. Suited for Audio. So it shouldn't be the media used for a hands free set.

Comment: Handsfree devices are visible routes in an AVAudioSession

Comment: I have same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iPhone considers the car an accessory you can get the connected accessories by calling:

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
```

This will return an array of `EAAccessory` objects which you can then query to get certain information like the name: `accessory.name`.

I don't know for certain of this will work with cars having never tried it myself (I have used it with other accessories), so I would suggest that you create a test app that logs the connected accessories to the screen on demand and test it yourself.

Here's the documentation for [EAAccessoryManager](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessoryManager_class/index.html) and [EAAccessory](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessory_class/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already tested that and the car don't appear in the connected accessories. I think the EAAccessoryManager only shows accessories under the MFI program. Is there any way to detect accessories that don´t follow the MFI program?

Comment: As far as I'm aware the only objective-c frameworks for bluetooth are CoreBluetooth and ExternalAccessory. That's not to say there isn't a third party one that will work with non MFI accessories. Other than that you could take a look at the IOKit or some C libraries. You have to be careful as some of these frameworks are private and your app will be rejected by apple if you link them in your project.

Comment: Sorry I can't help further